# How to transform MultiMap<String, String> to MultiMap<String,Integer>?

Tags: java, guava

I got the following `Multimap`, How could I transform it to  `MultiMap<String,Integer>` ?

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap= // contents here
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Did you read a documentation before posting the question? There's a good [Wiki covering this topic](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) on a project page, too.

Comment: @Xaerxess yeah but yet sadly it doesn't mention how to transformEntries

Answer (score 9):

Use [`Multimaps#transformValues(Multimap, Function)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#transformValues-com.google.common.collect.Multimap-com.google.common.base.Function-):

```
Multimap<String, Integer> transformed = Multimaps.transformValues(multimap,
    new Function<String, Integer>() {
        @Override public Integer apply(String value) {
          return Integer.valueOf(value);
        }
    });
```

See also:

- [NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap)
- [CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Multimaps](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#multimaps)
- [FunctionalExplained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained)

or in Java 8+:

```
Multimap<String, Integer> transformed =
    Multimaps.transformValues(multimap, Integer::valueOf);
```

Comment: @Macon Why have you unaccepted and unupvoted the answer then?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to go through all the values in the first map and use String.parseInt() on them, and then add them to a new map.